# Get latest date timestamp for particular row for a particular day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table

| ID | status | startdate | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 | 2023-03-01 13:15:10 |
| 2 | error | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 | null |
| 3 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 |
| 1 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:20:10 | 2023-03-01 13:22:10 |
| 2 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:22:10 | 2023-03-01 13:25:10 |
| 2 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:24:10 | 2023-03-01 13:26:10 |

In am expecting below o/p

| ID | status | startdate | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:20:10 | 2023-03-01 13:22:10 |
| 2 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:24:10 | 2023-03-01 13:26:10 |
| 3 | completed | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 | 2023-03-01 13:12:10 |

Now I want to get below result
The status of ID 2 and 3 ,whose end date is not null and start date of these IDs should be latest timestamp for that particular day.

As for same ID many entries will be happen for same day

I tried it with multiple ways but not getting the exact results

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve, based on the source data you've provided. Please ensure you include enough source data to demonstrate all the possible scenarios

Comment: I am using Oracle db @gotqn

Answer (score 1):

You can use ranking function to order the dates for each [group](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d7456/2):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  ID NUMBER,
  status VARCHAR2(20),
  startdate DATE,
  enddate DATE
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'completed', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:12:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:15:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'error', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:12:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), null);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3, 'completed', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:12:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:12:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 'completed', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:20:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:22:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'completed', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:22:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:25:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, 'completed', TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:24:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('2023-03-01 13:26:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

SELECT ID, status, startdate, enddate
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ID,
    status,
    startdate,
    enddate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY startdate DESC) AS rn
  FROM my_table

)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying @gotn.    But it is possible that for one particular ID today's end date is null but there's timestamp entry for yesterday for the same ID. In this case it will give me yesterday 'status but I don't want it. I want entry for today only

Comment: Is there any function like utc or something ,which can be used to sort out the record for current date only?

Comment: We are ordering by start date, not end date. But you can change the logic in the ROW_NUMBER as you like.